# Email notification of Wordpress issue (DIVI) after changing wp-admin background login to not standard

Tags: wordpress, background, wp-admin

I get email notifications of website issue caused after changing wp-admin standard background login to different one. I used Cerber plugin to configure that change. It recognized issue by Divi (but it's not). How to turf off this notification or add exception to Wordpress? is it configureable?

It's look like that

> Blockquote Howdy!

Since WordPress 5.2 there is a built-in feature that detects when a plugin or theme causes a fatal error on your site, and notifies you with this automated email.

In this case, WordPress caught an error with your theme, Divi.

First, visit your website (https://*******.pl/) and check for any visible issues. Next, visit the page where the error was caught (https://********.pl/wp-login.php) and check for any visible issues.